Writing a theme manager for QML 5 application that uses the Material theme benefits while it can be extended
I want to implement a ThemeManager component that uses the Material theme inside while it is extensible via adding properties.
I have two files for my custom themes:
CustomDarkTheme.qml:
import QtQuick 2.15

ThemeBase {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        theme.themeMode = "Dark";
        theme.primaryColor = "#FFA000";
        theme.accentColor = "#FFC107";
        theme.foregroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        theme.backgroundColor = "#263238";
    }
}

CustomLightTheme.qml:
import QtQuick 2.15

ThemeBase {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        theme.themeMode = "Light";
        theme.primaryColor = "#FFC107";
        theme.accentColor = "#03A9F4";
        theme.foregroundColor = "#5D4037";
        theme.backgroundColor = "#FFF3E0";
    }
}

These two files are the templates for my theme files and this template is defined in ThemeBase.qml file in below:
import QtQuick 2.15

QtObject {
    id: theme
    readonly property string themeMode: "Light"
    readonly property color primaryColor: "#FFA000"
    readonly property color accentColor: "#FFC107"
    readonly property color foregroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    readonly property color backgroundColor: "#263238"
}

In ThemeManager.qml file, I will load these themes via a loader object and on its onLoaded signal, the customization on Material theme is done. Also the change in currentTheme value, reloads the theme.
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

QtObject {
    id: themeManager
    property string currentTheme: "CustomLightTheme.qml"
    property alias theme: themeLoader.item

    Loader {
        id: themeLoader
        source: Qt.resolvedUrl("./CustomLightTheme.qml")
        onLoaded: {
            applyTheme(themeLoader.item)
        }
    }

    function applyTheme(theme) {
        Material.theme = theme.themeMode === "Light" ? Material.Light : Material.Dark;
        Material.primary = theme.primaryColor;
        Material.accent = theme.accentColor;
        Material.foreground = theme.foregroundColor;
        Material.background = theme.backgroundColor;
    }

    onCurrentThemeChanged: {
        themeLoader.source = currentTheme;
    }
}

after all an object of the ThemeManager is created in another file that uses the Material theme which is customized in the creation of the ThemeManager:
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import "../theme"

Item {
    id: root

    TemplateManager {
        id: templateManager
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: bg
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: Material.background
        Button {
            id: testBtn
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 200
            height: 60
            background: Rectangle {
                id: btBackground
                color: Material.color(Material.LightBlue)
                anchors.fill: parent

                Text {
                    id: btnText
                    text: qsTr("Switch Theme")
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
            onClicked: {
                console.info("Hello from clicked!")
                if (templateManager.currentTheme === "CustomLightTheme.qml"){
                    templateManager.currentTheme = "CustomDarkTheme.qml"
                } else {
                    templateManager.currentTheme = "CustomLightTheme.qml"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

My goal is to use the standards of the Material theme, like the standard sizing of the Controls and ... while being able to add more properties to the ThemeManager that I can use them for custom theming.
Now, when I use this setup with Pyside2 API, the page that uses the theme manager does not loaded and there are no errors in the terminal.
Please let me know that is this approach a correct way to achieve the goal specified above and if yes, how should I solve the problem.
thanks!

I think it should give an error about the Loader in the QtObject (something with default property). Are you sure you are getting all the logs?
